# Как вывести информацию?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте подскажите как вывести информацию, шото никак не доходит как 
есть файл dat и внем скажем есть запись одна только  cry.jpg<|>информация<|>информация2

```
 $page_descr = 'информация ';
 $page_keyws = 'информация ';
 $page_img = 'cry.jpg';
```

нужно чтоб вывелось на странице в метатегах

```
    require ('data/page_about_settings.php');

 function page_about_details($about_sym_link)
{
    $url = $about_sym_link . "/data/page_about_details.dat";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,       "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,  false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,          false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,  true); //если выпадает ошибка на эту строку - попробуйте закомментировать её
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,             $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,         $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,  true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,  5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,         5);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    //$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    // разбиваем по строкам

    $res = explode("\n", $data);

    foreach($res as $rows) {

        $row = explode("<|>", $rows);
        if (!strripos($rows, "<|>")) continue; //Но вот так наверно лучше будет.


    $page_img = $row[0];  //НЕ выводится в наружу
    $page_descr = $row[1]; //НЕ выводится в наружу
    $page_keyws = $row[2];  //НЕ выводится в наружу

    }
    return $data;
    //return ($httpcode >= 200 && $httpcode < 300) ? $print : false;
}
echo page_about_details($about_sym_link);

var_dump(page_about_details($about_sym_link));
```

Comment: вместо `return false;` нужно возвращать массив, к примеру `return $data;` . То есть, использовать функцию только для curl - все остальные операции пропишите в другой пользовательской функции _(или в нескольких функциях, если необходимо)_ . Ну и результат работы функции надо сохранять в переменную, чтобы иметь доступ к полученному значению.

Comment: вы не поняли мне нужно вывести вот  эти $page_img = недоходит как в наружу вывети

Comment: я понял ) Выше уже ответил _(пока вы камент написали)_

Answer (score 0):

Вы никак не возвращаете нужные значения из функции и в цикле `foreach` при каждом проходе перезаписываете переменные `$page_img`, `$page_descr`, `$page_keyws`.

Нужно поменять:

```
foreach($res as $rows) {

    $row = explode("<|>", $rows);
    if (!strripos($rows, "<|>")) continue; //Но вот так наверно лучше будет.
    $img .= $row[0];  //выводится
    $descr .= $row[1];//выводится
    $keyws .= $row[2];//выводится

    var_dump($img);//выводится

    $page_img = $row[0];  //НЕ выводится в наружу
    $page_descr = $row[1]; //НЕ выводится в наружу
    $page_keyws = $row[2];  //НЕ выводится в наружу

}
return false;
```

На

```
$page = [];
foreach($res as $row) {

    $row = explode("<|>", $rows);
    if (!strripos($rows, "<|>")) continue; //Но вот так наверно лучше будет.
    $img .= $row[0];  //выводится
    $descr .= $row[1];//выводится
    $keyws .= $row[2];//выводится

    var_dump($img);//выводится

$page[] = [
    'page_img' => $row[0],
    'page_descr' => $row[1],
    'page_keyws' => $row[2]
];  

}
return $page;
```

Результатом работы функции будет возвращение массива `$page` с нужными значениями.

Пример вызова функции:

```
$page = page_about_details($about_sym_link); // $about_sym_link - в переменной нужная ссылка
var_dump($page);
```

И не понятен смысл переменной `$img`, `$descr`, `$keyws` в цикле `foreach`.

Вывод meta, пример:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?=$page[0]['page_descr'];?>" />
```

**UPD**

```
foreach($res as $row) {

    $row = explode("<|>", $rows);
    if (!strripos($rows, "<|>")) continue; //Но вот так наверно лучше будет.
    $img .= $row[0];  //выводится
    $descr .= $row[1];//выводится
    $keyws .= $row[2];//выводится

    var_dump($img);//выводится

    $page_img[] = $row[0];
    $page_descr[] = $row[1];
    $page_keyws[] = $row[2];

}
return false;
```

Заменить:

```
function page_about_details($about_sym_link)
```

на:

```
function page_about_details($about_sym_link, &$page_img, &$page_descr, &$page_keyws)
```

Пример вызова функции:

```
$page_img = [];
$page_descr = [];
$page_keyws = [];

$page = page_about_details($about_sym_link, $page_img, $page_descr, $page_keyws); // $about_sym_link - в переменной нужная ссылка
var_dump($page_img, $page_descr, $page_keyws);
```

[PHP Функции](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.functions.php)

**UPD2**

В html делаете по примеру:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?=implode(',', $page_descr);?>" />
```

**UPD3**

Весь Ваш код с правками

```
require ('data/page_about_settings.php');

function page_about_details($about_sym_link){
    $url = $about_sym_link . "/data/page_about_details.dat";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,       "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,  false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,          false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,  true); //если выпадает ошибка на эту строку - попробуйте закомментировать её
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,             $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,         $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,  true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,  5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,         5);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    //$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    // разбиваем по строкам

    $res = explode("\n", $data);
    $page = [];
    foreach($res as $row) {
        $row = explode("<|>", $row);
        $page[] = [
            'page_img' => $row[0],
            'page_descr' => $row[1],
            'page_keyws' => $row[2]
        ];  
    }
    return $page;
}

$page = page_about_details($about_sym_link); // $about_sym_link - в переменной нужная ссылка
var_dump($page);
/*
array(1) {
  [0]=>
    array(3) {
        [page_descr]=>
        string() "информация",
        [page_keyws]=>
        string() "информация",
        [page_img]=>
        string() "cry.jpg"
    }
}
*/
```

В html, прописываем meta:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?=$page[0]['page_descr'];?>" />
<meta name="keywords" content="<?=$page[0]['page_keyws'];?>" />
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75359/discussion-on-answer-by-razik---).